# Meteor: Prevent Live Update/Re-Rendering of one section

Tags: meteor

In Meteor, how can I prevent certain collection fields or certain portions of the page from being affected by the Live Updating/Re-Rendering system?

I found some answers such as {{#constant}} and {{#isolate}} but they are depreciated now.

Also reactive: false doesn't seem to work for me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `Tracker.nonreactive`. That lets you access it a reactive data source non-reactively. For example:

```html
<template name="tmplt">
  The counter is {{getCounter}}.
</template>
```

```js
Template.tmplt.helpers({
  getCounter: function () {
    return Tracker.nonreactive(function () {
      return Session.get("counter");
    });
  }
});
```

Changes to the "counter" session variable will not cause `tmplt` to update.

When passing a database query to `#each`, make sure you call `fetch`:

```js
// Don't do this
return Tracker.nonreactive(function () {
  return Collection.find(...);
});

// Do this
return Tracker.nonreactive(function () {
  return Collection.find(...).fetch();
});
```